# jqGrid custom formatter option "unformat" doesnt work

Tags: jqgrid, formatter

jqGrid custom formatter option "unformat" doesnt work when supplied with function.

I am supplying function to this option.
[custom formatter example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)
suppose to work but its not working.

My main purpose of having unformat function is to give proper value to the sort function (when you sort by clicking on the sortable column header) which calls unformat and formatter supplied to the colModel.

Here is my code, (all the modules are included for jquery UI and jqgrid.)

```
<link href="../css/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>


    $("#GridTable").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],
    colModel: [{name:'id',index:'id', align:'left', width:'260px'},
                {name:'col1',index:'col1', width:'170px'},
                {name:'col2',index:'col2', width:'160px'},
                {name:'col3',index:'col3', sorttype:'float', width:'110px',unformat: unformatterFunction, formatter: formatterFunction },
                {name:'col4',index:'col4', sorttype:'float', width:'110px'}
             ],
    altRows: true,
    caption: "Test Data",
    height: '100%',
    autowidth : true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
});

function unformatterFunction(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    if(cellvalue=="-"){
        return "0";
    }
    return cellvalue;
}

function formatterFunction(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
    if(cellvalue > 15){
        return "-";
    }
    return cellvalue;
}
```

I have spend lot of hours to trace the call into grid.base.js and found no way that goes to  jquery.fmatter.js where the unformatFunction gets called for every row.
My doubt is unformatFunction is not getting called while sorting.

I just confirmed by editing [the example](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), that it is not working, something is horribly wrong. i can't think of any mistakes. its simply dont call the unformat function specified in colModel.

Comment: What if I want to change of the css for the add/edit form of jqgrid ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need customize to sorting of the local jqGrid the usage of custom unformatter is the wrong way. What you need is to use `sorttype` as the function. Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324613/jqgrid-with-custom-sorttype/3329852#3329852) including the demo or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294535/how-do-i-implement-custom-sort-to-a-specific-column-after-jqgrid-has-been-generat/5296935#5296935).

The simplest way to use the `sorttype` as the function is to return from the function converted data which should be used to define in the corresponding compare operation to define the order of the row in the grid.