# jqgrid: unformat is not called while sorting

Tags: jqgrid

As per the jqGrid documentation, if you provide a custom formatter in colOptions, you should also provide an 'unformat' key, which gets called during sort operation. However, I don't see this happening ie, the unformat function doesn't get called. Here is an extremely simple example:

As you can see, the console.log line in the unformat_salary function never gets called. Even when you click on the Salary header to sort it. The sort seems to work but it's sorted lexically and I want a custom sort. Providing 'sorttype' as a function would do what I want but I'm wondering why unformat is not getting called when the Documentation specifically says it gets called during sort operations.

JQGRID Test

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        th.ui-th-column div{
            white-space:normal !important;
            height:auto !important;
            padding:2px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            createGrid();
        });
        function createGrid() {
            $("#jqgrid-table").jqGrid({
                colNames:['First<br/>Name', 'Last Name', 'Age', 'Salary', 'Type'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100},
                    {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100},
                    {name:'age', index:'age', width:50},
                    {name:'salary', index: 'salary', width:50, sortable:true, formatter: salary_formatter, unformat:unformat_salary},
                    {name:'type', index:'type', width: 56}
                ],
                width: 800,
                datatype:'local',                   
                pager: '#pager2',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption:"JSON Example"
            });
            var searchOptions = {
                caption: 'Filter...',
                multipleSearch:true,
                closeAfterSearch:true,
                closeAfterReset:true,
                Find: 'Filter'
            };                
            jQuery("#jqgrid-table").jqGrid('navGrid',
                                    '#pager2', 
                                    {search:true, edit:false, add:false, del:false, refresh:false}, 
                                    null, null, null, searchOptions
                                    );
            var data = getData();
            for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var r = data[i];
                jQuery("#jqgrid-table").addRowData(r.id, r);
            }
        }

        function getData() {
            return [
                   {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'XXX',  age:'30',  salary:'1500', type: 'Nice'},
                   {id:2, firstName: 'Ashley', lastName:'YYY', age:'31',  salary:'1300', type:'Nicer'},
                   {id:3, firstName:'Smith', lastName:'ZZZ', age:'23',    salary:'1301', type:'Nicest'},
                   {id:4, firstName:'Sarah', lastName:'Aster', age:'45',  salary:'530',  type:'Nicest'},
                   {id:5, firstName:'Michelle', lastName:'Crazy', age:'30', salary:'1423', type:'Nicest'}
            ];
        }

        function salary_formatter(cellvalue) {
            return cellvalue.replace(/^(\d\d)/,'$1,');
        }

        function unformat_salary(cellvalue) {
            console.log('U : ' + cellvalue); // THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED !
            return Number(cellvalue.replace(/,/g,''));
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='jqgrid-div'>
          <table id='jqgrid-table'></table>
         <div id="pager2"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the meaning of `unformat` function. It will be soleved only if you get the contain of the cells, rows or columns. For example if you use `getCell`, `getRowData`, `getCol` or close [jqGrid methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). If you use `datatype:'local'` (like in your example) the [sorttype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) property define how the column will be sorted. In case of custom sorting you can use [sorttype as function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324613/jqgrid-with-custom-sorttype/3329852#3329852). The function can has two parameters: `cellValue` and `rowData`. The last parameter represent the non-formatted data from the current row.

In your case the you can use

```
sorttype:function(cellvalue){
    return unformat_salary(cellvalue);
}
```