# JqGrid sorting & grouping dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, jqgrid, grouping

I have the following issue: I have a large grid, that is primarily sorted by date since the load. This particular table also has the ability to group, as shown in the following image:

(Sorry for posting an image like this, but thanks to the spam filter, i cant directly insert one here)

[image]

Issue is that when i group by date (do note that this behavior is not observed in other columns other than date) this happens:

[image]

But if i order the date in to the other way, such behavior is no longer observed

I should note also that this implementation is under ASP.MVC 3. I tried to format the date differently, but without avail.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem which you has? The items seems be grouped and correct sorted. All groups are collapsed like you probably wanted (`groupCollapse: true`). What's wrong in the grid?

Comment: Hi @Oleg, thanks for you input. 

Problem is that the picture #2 depicts the grouped sorting in descendant fashion. 
As you can see, the data is incorrectly sorted by year (first must be 2012 tasks, then 2011 tasks, then 2010 tasks, and so on). If you go the other way (ascendant order), this does not happen. I hope its clearer now. Thanks again for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is only the order of sorting (see comments to the question) I think one could solve the problem by the usage `sorttype` as function. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329852/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) for details.