# How to sort "days ago" formatted date in jqGrid?

Tags: date, sorting, jqgrid, format, days

How can I sort the "days ago" formatted date in jqGrid ? When I sort the grid currently, it can't distinguish between "11 hours ago" and "1 days ago". So "1 day ago" is sorted on the top instead of "11 hours ago".

**Please refer this image of the grid.

[image]

My jqGrid has the following code. **recommendationData** is JSON. **Posted** column is the date.

```js
$("#tblRecommendationList").jqGrid({
    data: recommendationData,
    datatype: 'local',
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Title', label: 'Title', width: 210, resizable: true },
        { name: 'Channel', label: 'Content Type', width: 120, resizable: true },
        { name: 'StatusNumber', label: 'Status', width: 120, resizable: true,
            formatter: GetStatusCode },
        { name: 'Posted', label: 'Posted', width: 120, resizable: true },
        { name: 'RecordId', label: 'RecordId', hidden: true }
    ],
    loadtext: 'Loading...',
    loadui: 'block',
    emptyDataText: "No Recommendations to display",
    shrinkToFit: true,
```

The date is passed in the following manner.

```cs
    ...
        returnList =
            (
                from i in responseList
                select new InQuiraRecommendation
                {
                    StatusNumber = i.statusnumber,
                    Title = i.title,
                    Text = i.text,
                    Posted = GetDaysAgo(i.dateadded),
                    CaseNumber = i.casenumber,
                    Priority = i.priority,
                    Channel = i.channel,
                    RecordId = i.recordid,

                }
            ).ToList();
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

**GetDaysAgo( ) changes the "2012-09-13 07:00:00 Etc/GMT" date format to "Days ago" format.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts with the usage of `datatype: 'local'` with the data prepared on the server. If you would uses `datatype: 'json'` the *server* would be responsible for sorting of the data and you could just returns correctly sorted data to jqGrid.

Another way would be to implement `GetDaysAgo` method, which converts dates posted back in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format to texts like "11 hours ago" or "1 days ago", *on the client side* as JavaScript code. So you can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) (and [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting)) to display the data.

One more option is to define your custom `sorttype` property for `'Posted'` column defined *as function*. The function could returns for example the number of hours which will be used *instead* of texts "11 hours ago" or "1 days ago" for sorting by the column.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329852/315935) is the first reference to custom sorting and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) you will find some code example which could help you. You can simplify the implementation of custom sorting (implementation of `sorttype` as function) if you would create hidden column with sortable string (ISO 8601 for example). Inside of `sorttype` function you have access to any other data of the row per the second parameter of `sorttype` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001822/315935) for more information). In the way you can just return ISO 8601 representation of `'Posted'` (from hidden column) as the result of `sorttype`  function.

Comment: Implemented the GetDaysAgo method  as JavaScript and used custom formatter. Worked perfectly. Thank you very much Oleg.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add 'dateadded' to your InQuiraRecommendation class and include that as a hidden field on your grid, then use that as your sort column.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I still need to use the "Posted" column to be able to sort date in Asc. or Desc. order. The date format should be in "days ago" format. How can I use the hidden "DateAdded" column to sort the "Posted" column ?

Comment: Probably a couple of ways to handle...I'd use onSortCol and change the index from Posted to your hidden date column when Posted is clicked.  http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events